# IG PYTHON fetch_historical_prices_by_epic_and_date_range raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'last'

Tags: python

I do get the error in the title 'raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'last'' depending on the time set to download price data.

When start_date=str(dt_to.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + " 02:00:00" then I get raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'last'
When start_date=str(dt_to.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + " 03:00:00" then data is downloaded without any error.

`def price_dlw_ig(lbl_log, lbl_progress_status, tg_table, tickers, dt_fr, dt_to):

''' Download prices from IG API and save output as csv file in datafeed directory '''

start_date=str(dt_to.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))  + " 02:00:00"
end_date = str(dt_to.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))  + " 24:00:00"

for i in range(0, len(tickers)):

```
response = ig_service.fetch_historical_prices_by_epic_and_date_range(epic=tickers[i], resolution= tg_table  + 'Min', start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
        
df_bid = response['prices']['bid']        
df_bid['Volume'] = response['prices']['last']['Volume']`
```

Also, if I add to the code print(response['prices']) when start_date=str(dt_to.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + " 02:00:00" then I do see that the downloading did work partially.

```
                 bid                                 ask           \
                Open     High      Low    Close     Open     High
```

DateTime
2023-10-02 02:00:00 15412.6 15416.3 15409.1 15414.5 15419.6 15423.3
2023-10-02 02:05:00 15415.7 15419.6 15414.4 15416.7 15422.7 15426.6
2023-10-02 02:10:00 15417.6 15426.5 15417.6 15420.5 15424.6 15433.5
2023-10-02 02:15:00 15419.6 15464.0 15418.7 15462.0 15426.6 15469.0
2023-10-02 02:20:00 15462.5 15462.5 15455.5 15456.0 15467.5 15467.5
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2023-10-02 23:40:00 15197.5 15197.5 15197.5 15197.5 15204.5 15204.5
2023-10-02 23:45:00 15197.6 15197.9 15197.6 15197.6 15204.6 15204.9
2023-10-02 23:50:00 15198.4 15209.7 15198.4 15209.1 15205.4 15216.7
2023-10-02 23:55:00 15208.6 15210.9 15208.6 15210.0 15215.6 15217.9
2023-10-03 00:00:00 15211.7 15213.5 15207.2 15210.4 15218.7 15220.5

```
                 Low    Close
```

DateTime
2023-10-02 02:00:00 15416.1 15421.5
2023-10-02 02:05:00 15421.4 15423.7
2023-10-02 02:10:00 15424.6 15427.5

The difference is that response['prices']['last'] is missing in the downloaded data set.

Any clue what's going on ?

Thks.

gfx